# Encoding of N objects distributed into containers

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Does anyone have an idea on how to use binary enconding for distributing `N` objects into `C` containers?

I have 70 objects to distribute into 25 containers.

All can store up to 6 objects, except for one, which can store up to 14 objects.

I tried to solve it like this:

- Chromossome with 25 genes, sized 2^4 each.
- Now given an individual, I divide all numbers in the chromossome by their sum.
- Now I have 25 floating point numbers representing the proportion of objects in each container
- When I multiply these proportions by 70 I have how many objects should go to each container, but my results aren't integers, so I round them up or down, which is closest.

Since the amount of rounding ups and down aren't the same, my final distribution can have anything between ~65-75.

I know I could create a penalty system to penalize the solutions in which the amount of distributed objects is not equal to 70. But I was wondering If I could fix this using another enconding logic.

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What are the requirements for the distribution? Should each container be filled by a similar percentage? Or should each container have an equal number of items until space runs out in the smaller ones? Or can you just start filling container to their limit one by one and have the possibility for empty containers?

Comment: @Thakkie The solution shouldn't favor any situation, like filling a container before going to the next. The distribution should be somewhat random, and the algorithm would work on the optimization. There is no other requirement, any container could be fulfilled, empty or anyting in between.

Comment: Do you really need a binary encoding, or you can use for example an integer to code a gene ?

Comment: @Bertrand125 Yes, I must use binary encoding.